# MySQL table not populating by form input

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm very new to MySQL and its programming so sorry for putting up such simple question. I'm unable to understand why my MySQL database is not populating.

I created this html form:

```
<form action="demo.php" method="post"/>
<p>Input 1: <input type="text" name="input1"/></p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit""/>
</form>
```

and tried to link it with MySQL database using following code:

```
$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
$db_selectd = mysqli_select_db($link, DB_NAME);

$value=$_POST['input1'];

 $sql = "INSERT INTO demo(input1) VALUES ('$value')";
 ?>
```

Please help.

This is the new code now:

```
$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
$db_selectd = mysqli_select_db($link, DB_NAME);

$sql = "INSERT INTO demo(input1) VALUES (?)";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $value);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
 ?>
```

Comment: Does your code even execute the statement? Simply initializing a variable with the SQL statement won't just run it.

Comment: Query should be executed.

Answer (score 1):

You totally missed the `mysqli_query` part. How can just assigning to `$sql` will execute?

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO demo(input1) VALUES ('$value')";
mysqli_query($link, $sql);
```

Moreover, your program is vulnerable to **SQL Injection**. Make sure you give:

```
$value = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $value);
```

Or, best of all, it is better to use **prepared statements**, as said by [Mark Baker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/324584/mark-baker):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO demo(input1) VALUES (?)";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $value);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

Comment: If OP is using MySQLi, the 21st century recommendation should be to use prepared statements and bind variables, not simply escaping

Comment: `$sql = "INSERT INTO demo(input1) VALUES (?)"; $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql); mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $value); mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);`

Comment: @PraveenKumar Did everything you mentioned, still isn't able to fill the table of database:

Now the code is: 

<?php
define('DB_NAME', 'demo');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
$db_selectd = mysqli_select_db($link, DB_NAME);
 
$sql = "INSERT INTO demo(input1) VALUES (?)";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $value);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
 ?>

Comment: @PraveenKumar I was just testing the code for simple form to see how can I fill the database.

I need to develop the whole form based on it and upload it to my server for data collection.

Comment: @Himanshu Wow. Can you read what have you given here? If so you are a genius. Man, common sense. [Edit] the question and add please.

Comment: `<?php
    define('DB_NAME', 'demo');
    define('DB_USER', 'root');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
    define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

    $link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
    $db_selectd = mysqli_select_db($link, DB_NAME);
 
    $sql = "INSERT INTO demo(input1) VALUES (?)";
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $value);

    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
     ?>`